# iOS - Size of Image vs. Size of ImageView

Tags: ios, swift, image

just want to see if I'm on the right track here is understanding the performance trade-offs of placing various image sizes into image views.

If I have a large image, will the image load faster if I place it in a correspondingly large imageView versus placing it in a smaller imageView?

Answer (score 3):

No, the loading time depends on the file, and if the image is large, and its file Size is large, it will load slower than a small images on the same image View.
To make it clear, image view doesn't affect loading performance, image size (File size) does affect performance.

Comment: Thanks! My app gets photos from users. It seems these photos typically are very large 720x1280. And displaying it back to the user (from server) in an imageView takes 10-20 seconds. Am I better off resizing this photo down to increase performance? However I do notice the quality of the image goes down (even though I'm maintaining aspect ratio).

Comment: how do you get does images? There are way to lower it size. For Example I use this function to reduce size when uploading user images to a server. let imgData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(img, 0.4)

Comment: I get the images from the UIImagePickerController. Yes maybe I need to lower the size before uploading to the server. Perhaps I should also think about compression?

Comment: Is this compression the same as gzip compression?

Comment: I Not sure, so can't answer that.

Answer (score 0):

Answering you r question first, size of image is not directly proportional to imageview i.e. regardless of your imageview size, you image will take time based on the size of image.

Now, if you have a task in which you need to show user images & on click you need to share that image, you need to maintain 2 copies for showing take resized copy & while sharing pick image from original position. In this way, your loading will be fast & while sharing you will be able to share original image itself.